# Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined at Google Geo Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

so this is my set up on my index.html. the api key has been generated at `console.developers.google.com` and I don't think that it was causing an error.
 the problem is the `arrayToDataTable` is undefined, I put it on my index.html just to test if this would work but in my real apps it was separated to a component.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
        google.charts.load('current', {
          'packages': ['geochart'],
          'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyC1PKyylEm8Xe0l0fnv81tuuUS-eOlrRCQ'
        });

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff());

        function drawStuff() {
          var MapData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Code", "Name", "Value"],
            ["PH-14", "Autonomous Region in Muslim Mindanao (ARMM)", 1],
            ["PH-05", "Bicol (Region V)", 2],
            ["PH-02", "Cagayan Valley (Region II)", 3],
            ["PH-40", "Calabarzon (Region IV-A)",4 ],
            ["PH-13", "Caraga (Region XIII)", 5],
            ["PH-03", "Central Luzon (Region III)", 6],
            ["PH-07", "Central Visayas (Region VII)", 7],
            ["PH-15", "Cordillera Administrative Region (CAR)", 8],
            ["PH-11", "Davao (Region XI)", 9],
            ["PH-08", "Eastern Visayas (Region VIII)", 10],
            ["PH-01", "Ilocos (Region I)", 11],
            ["PH-41", "Mimaropa (Region IV-B)", 12],
            ["PH-00", "National Capital Region Pambansang Punong", 13],
            ["PH-10", "Northern Mindanao (Region X)", 14],
            ["PH-12", "Soccsksargen (Region XII)", 15],
            ["PH-06", "Western Visayas (Region VI)", 16],
            ["PH-09", "Zamboanga Peninsula (Region IX)", 17]
          ]);


          console.log(MapData);

          // Set chart options
          var MapOptions = {
            'region': 'PH',
            'resolution': 'provinces',
            'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
          };

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
          chart.draw(MapData, MapOptions);
        };
    </script>
```

I really don't know what's missing in the set up.

Comment: try console.log(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable);  is function?

Comment: @InferOn it was undefined. but when I try the console.log(google) everything are present. weird. but when I try console.log(google.visualization). it was undefined.

Comment: I have modified an official jsfiddle and seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/6fru9eo6/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, remove the parentheses in ...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff) // not drawStuff()
```

When you have the parenthesis, you are passing the result of calling the function, but the API wants to be given a handler function (not its result).

Furthermore, instead of ...

```
["Code", "Name", "Value"],
```

...try using the label syntax, like so...

```
[{label: 'Code', type: 'string'},
{label: 'Name', type: 'string'},
{label: 'Value', type: 'number'}],
```

The API should be able to figure it out without this change, but this is a "just-in-case-its-needed" sort of change that also makes the code more self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with this console online for web html js css :

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
      function drawStuff() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["Code", "Name", "Value"],
            ["PH-14", "Autonomous Region in Muslim Mindanao (ARMM)", 1],
            ["PH-05", "Bicol (Region V)", 2],
            ["PH-02", "Cagayan Valley (Region II)", 3],
            ["PH-40", "Calabarzon (Region IV-A)",4 ],
            ["PH-13", "Caraga (Region XIII)", 5],
            ["PH-03", "Central Luzon (Region III)", 6],
            ["PH-07", "Central Visayas (Region VII)", 7],
            ["PH-15", "Cordillera Administrative Region (CAR)", 8],
            ["PH-11", "Davao (Region XI)", 9],
            ["PH-08", "Eastern Visayas (Region VIII)", 10],
            ["PH-01", "Ilocos (Region I)", 11],
            ["PH-41", "Mimaropa (Region IV-B)", 12],
            ["PH-00", "National Capital Region Pambansang Punong", 13],
            ["PH-10", "Northern Mindanao (Region X)", 14],
            ["PH-12", "Soccsksargen (Region XII)", 15],
            ["PH-06", "Western Visayas (Region VI)", 16],
            ["PH-09", "Zamboanga Peninsula (Region IX)", 17]
          ]);

          // Set chart options
          var options = {
            'region': 'PH',
            'resolution': 'provinces',
            'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
          };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case use angular 9, i consume WS service and next i try to send value on arrayToDataTable and ComboChart or GeoChart, and have the same error.

i fix issues i call the same function until all components angular is ready. add google chart  on asset folder in angular and then i call you on index.html

i hope helpfully.

Example

```js
your_function_name(){
    your_ws_name().subscribe(
        (data) => {

            try {
                //is ok
            }
            catch(e){
                //to make until all elements google char on ready.
                if (e.toString().includes('arrayToDataTable') || 
                        e.toString().includes('ComboChart')) {
                    this.your_function_name();
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```